# converting epoch time from multiple lines in a log file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, timestamps

I'm trying to find a way to batch convert the epoch timestamp from each line of a log file.

From what I understand I should follow this process.

1. search the log for all iterations of the epoch timestamps
2. put them through a function that converts them to a human readable format
3. in place edit them back into the normal log file output

Unfortunately I can't quite seem to get the formatting correct, here's a short snippet of the log file:

```
"[1508371955] Auto-save of retention data completed successfully.",
"[1508375555] Auto-save of retention data completed successfully.",
"[1508379155] Auto-save of retention data completed successfully.",
"[1508382755] Auto-save of retention data completed successfully.",
"[1508386355] Auto-save of retention data completed successfully."
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -F"[][]" '{cmd="date -d@" $2;cmd |getline $2; close(cmd)}1' infile

" Thu Oct 19 03:42:35 STD 2017  Auto-save of retention data completed successfully.",
" Thu Oct 19 04:42:35 STD 2017  Auto-save of retention data completed successfully.",
" Thu Oct 19 05:42:35 STD 2017  Auto-save of retention data completed successfully.",
" Thu Oct 19 06:42:35 STD 2017  Auto-save of retention data completed successfully.",
" Thu Oct 19 07:42:35 STD 2017  Auto-save of retention data completed successfully."
```

Here we set a shell command `date -d@$2` to a variable called `cmd`. Then with `cmd |getline $2` the `awk` reads a line and pass second field value to the `cmd` we open it, then we need close the command we opened via pipe, so we used [`close(cmd)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Close-Files-And-Pipes.html) here.

Comment: Thanks! I love that I can use that little ditty in a pipe.  For example, if I want to monitor a network connection and have an easy-to-read log of when it had problems, I can do something like: 
ping -s 16 -D -O -i 6 $1 | awk -F"[][]" '{cmd="date +%T -d@" $2;cmd |getline $2; close(cmd)}1' | tee pings